# create utf-8 encoding .xls file in android for use in Excel

Tags: android

This post has been changed, it is not valid comments, .CSV file was already on file.I changed this post from .csv file utf-8 problem to xls file.
I used the following function to create utf-8 encoding .xls file in android for use in Excel,It might be useful to others.
 for use the following code needs insert "jxl-2.6.9.jar" file (download from the internet) in libs folders.

public void ExportToxls(Cursor c, String fileName) {

```
    int rowCount = 0;  
    int colCount = 0;  


    File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pza/");


    if(!myDirectory.exists())
        myDirectory.mkdirs();


    String Fnamexls=fileName  + ".xls";




    File file = new File(myDirectory, Fnamexls);

    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook;
    try {
        int a = 1;
        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);

        rowCount = c.getCount();  
        colCount = c.getColumnCount(); 
        try {

            if (rowCount > 0) {  
                c.moveToFirst();  
                //   
                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {  
                    Label labelf = new Label(i,0,c.getColumnName(i));
                    sheet.addCell(labelf); 
                }  
                //   

                //   
                for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {  
                    c.moveToPosition(i);  


                    for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {  
                        Label labelrows = new Label(j,i,c.getString(j));

                        sheet.addCell(labelrows); 
                    }  

                } 
            }
        } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        workbook.write();

        try {
            workbook.close();
        } catch (WriteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} 


</code>
```

ExportToxls(c,"Filename"); // calling a function

Comment: Interesting. Which problem exactly?

Comment: the texts is like ØªØ§Ø±ÛŒØ® ,  
how to solve it?

Comment: Well i would not have to open that in excel to tell that something was wrong. Notepad would do. As you give no decent information or code we cannot help you. `I've created a function to get a .csv file in my own app `. What do you mean by that for instance?

Comment: excuse me. 
 my function code:

Comment: ????? It looks as if you don't want help. How can we help if you are not telling what you are doing? Please give decent info. How should WE know what is going on?

Comment: Ok. That function looks ok at first view. Please post in a separate code block some lines of the produced file.

Comment: `if (j != colCount - 1)  
                    bfw.write(c.getString(j) + ',');  
                else  
                   bfw.write(c.getString(j));  `. Better logic: `if (j ==0)  
                    bfw.write(c.getString(j));  
                else  
                   bfw.write("," + c.getString(j)); `.

Comment: greenapps, your answer is not fine. 
i have problem when i open the .csv file in microsoft Excel , the Non-English text is like " Ù…Ø³Ø§ÙØª Ø­Ù…Ù„ ØªØ§Ø±ÛŒØ® Ø³Ø§Ø¹Øª
" . How to solve it. and Please do not post negative vote

Comment: I did not vote at all. And you did not post some lines from your csv file in a code block here. Please do if you want help. `your answer is not fine` ? What is not fine about it?

Comment: this is my .csv file data 
{[code] Ø´Ù…Ø§Ø±Ù‡ Ù…Ø­Ù„ Ø¨Ø§Ø±Ú¯ÛŒØ±ÛŒ Ù…Ø³Ø§ÙØª Ø­Ù…Ù„ ØªØ§Ø±ÛŒØ® Ø³Ø§Ø¹Øª
1 Ø§Ø¨Ø§Ø¨ 655 1405 Û±Û´:Û±Û´:Û´Û¶
2 Ø¨Ù„Ø¨ 575 1405 Û±Û´:Û±Û´:ÛµÛ³
3 djf ÙˆÙ¾Ø±Ø§Ø¨ØªØ¨ 654 1405 Û±Ûµ:Û°Û¸:Û°Ûµ [code]}

Comment: Please post it in a code block. Not in a comment. We also cannot see lines now. Can you? No! And not only post these lines but also how they should look like instead. And tell where you copied/pasted these lines from? Which program did you use to open the file and copy some lines from it?

Comment: excuse me , i opened .csv file with microsoft excel and I've copied it here.

Comment: Well i expect you to do all the things i already asked you twice. Do not open the file with excel. Instead open with Notepad. Copy from Notepad and paste here. IN CODE BLOCK! I would not wonder if it looks ok in Notepad.

Comment: in notepad is fine, but in Excel is not fine. when i save or save as in notepad without change anything and setting, in excel show properly. 
<code>75,1405,۱۴:۱۴:۵۳
3,djf وپرابتب,654,1405,۱۵:۰۸:۰۵
</code>

Comment: ???? What is this? You posted in a comment. Why? Edit your post and put the lines in a codeblock. Where do these <code> ..</code> come from? Did you add them? Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
I would not wonder if it looks ok in Notepad
```

There is nothing wrong with your csv file as with Notepad the file is very ok. All characters show ok.

So you have troubles importing a csv file in Excel.

Well this is not the place to ask for such problems.

But i reckon that at openening the file in Excel you can tell it that it is utf-8. Please investigate.

Advice. Make such a fle in Excel itself (type some lines by hand) and save in utf-8. After that investigate how this file looks like in Notepad. Look at the differences.

Comment: All these cases had already been investigated. But the problem is still there. after than i write some line by hand , when i click save button , The following message appears "test.csv may contain features that are not compataible with csv ......." , needs to change encoding.

Comment: `needs to change encoding`. Who said that? Excel? You? Please be precise. Needs to change encoding from... to ... ?

Comment: me :) no . the Excel related to the problem of encoding the page that appears. you need a pic from it?  See these pages for non-English speakers is normal:) :)

Comment: Yes please post a picture. Cannot you change the encoding used by excel so all would work in a csv file?

Comment: Well that is not the picture i asked for. It contains already rubbish. Please type in by hand some lines with arabic texts so the picture will look ok.. And try to save that as .csv. Startt with a clean excelsheet.

Comment: It does not matter, both are one.

Comment: ????? Nonsense. So if you are typing arabic in a new clean empty excel sheet it will not show arabic? It will immediately show that rubbish? Well i do not believe you.

Comment: You are not familiar with this issue. I have no problem with writing Arabic text by hand. the problem is only in the .csv file. when i save_as .csv file. problem appears.